# "In my dreams, I've peered beyond its eyes, and into the cackling hell within us all"

Tags: futurama

In the wonderful Futurama episode, Möbius Dick, Leela goes nuts and chases a white space whale.

Since Futurama (and in particular Bender) is about 60% references, I wondered if the quote in the title is a reference, or even a direct quote, of something?

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you, @Richard, but this episode was based on *Moby Dick*, so unless there's a better quote from the book itself - and someone is willing to read the damn thing to find it - I'd say you're correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest I've seen is a canon quote from [Moby Dick](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm) that seems hauntingly similar;

> So in dreams, have I seen majestic Satan thrusting forth his tormented
>   colossal claw from the flame Baltic of Hell. But in gazing at such
>   scenes, it is all in all what mood you are in; if in the Dantean, the
>   devils will occur to you; if in that of Isaiah, the archangels.